# How to properly upload source maps to sentry for project with client and server parts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, source-maps, sentry

When I deploy a project with client part (javascript bundled with webpack) and server part (nodejs) I want to upload source maps of both parts to sentry associated with the same release.
Uploading server-side part source maps with client-side part using sentry’s webpack plugin doesn’t look proper. Or is it the right way?
Or I can upload server-side part using sentry-cli (create release - upload source maps - finalize release) then upload client-side part using sentry’s webpack plugin (which also creates release - uploads source maps - finalizes release) associated with the same release? Will uploading of the client-side part source maps discard previously uploaded server-side part source maps in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it is totally ok to upload sourcemaps of the server-side part using sentry-cli and then upload sourcemaps of the client-side part using sentry's webpack plugin. Both associated with the same release.

Comment: Does sentry show actual unminified file's line number in the crash if the source-maps are uploaded? I tried but its showing only till the bundle file in my nodejs express app.